# Replace ID for all tag after cloning node by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to change all ID after cloning node below by javascript or jquery.

```
<table id="1">
 <tr>
  <td id="RM_1"><button type="button" onclick="duplicateFunction(1)"></td>
  <td id="CL_1"><input id="[1][999]"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

when I clone node with ID = "1" I need to change 1 to 2 as in all ID tags below.

```
<table id="2">
 <tr>
  <td id="RM_2"><button type="button" onclick="duplicateFunction(2)"></td>
  <td id="CL_2"><input id="[2][999]"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Remark : The table id is unique id. I use simple number to explain the code.

### update

When user click duplicate button. The duplicateFunction will be called.
now , I can change table id but I can't change inside.

```
  function duplicateFunction(table_id){
    var myTable = document.getElementById(table_id);
    myClone = myTable.cloneNode(true);
    var newTableID = Date.now();
    myClone.id = newTableID;
    document.getElementById("AddingSpace").appendChild(myClone);
  }
```

because every tags have another features to do when user click.
that's the best way on this time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you really need ids?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  Worse case scenario, you should have already started down the path of changing the table id.  And then finding the nested ids and trying to replace them one at a time.  After figuring that out it is simply a question of efficiency, if the logic makes sense, and if it can be done better.

Comment: This example is the prime reason why putting `id` attributes on content which will be duplicated is not a good idea. Use common classes to relate elements to each other within cloned structures. I'd also suggest you use unobtrusive delegated event handlers instead of inline ones for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt along the lines suggested by Rory McCrossan. Instead of the individual ids of your elements inside the table I used shortened class names. The tables do not have actual ids but `dataset` attributes with `id` properties. This way it will not cause serious problems if ids should become double ...

My function calculates a `newid` on the basis of the number of already existing tables in the `#addingspace` div. This is not production ready either but probably less problematic than your original approach.

```js
const $trg=$('#addingspace');
$(document).on('click','.RM button',function(){
  let newid=$trg.find('table').length+2;
  $trg.append(
    $(this).closest('table').clone().data('id',newid) // set data-id 
           .find('.CL span').text(newid).end()        // set span and return cloned element
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-id="1">
 <tr>
  <td class="RM"><button type="button">duplicate</button></td>
  <td class="CL"><input /> id: <span>1</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="addingspace"></div>
```